# SQL inner join difference between explicit and implicit

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I was trying to solve #2 in [this practice problem set](http://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-joins-exercises.php). My attempt was this:

```
/* My attempt */
SELECT o.ord_no, o.purch_amt, c.cust_name, c.city
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN customer AS c
ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE o.purch_amt BETWEEN 500 AND 2000
```

But according to the solution of the site given [here](http://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-joins-exercise-2.php), it should be like this:

```
/* Correct solution */
SELECT a.ord_no, a.purch_amt, b.cust_name, b.city
FROM orders a, customer b
WHERE a.purch_amt
BETWEEN 500 AND 2000
```

I thought if we do not explicitly define `JOIN` type (as in the solution above), SQL would simply do an `INNER JOIN`? Obviously, my assumption was wrong. Could someone please explain me the difference between my attempt and the correct solution? Thank you!

Comment: In what sense is your assumption wrong? The 'correct' solution is gibberish.

Comment: Yours looks correct. Unless I misread the question, the "solution" is wrong (without "joining" on customer_id); and many here consider that answer's format (comma notation for joins) very poor form.

Comment: @Strawberry Do you think their correct solution is actually *wrong*? I ran both (mine and their "correct" solutions) in their web page and got two different sets of data...I'm confused.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thank you. Ignoring the poor form, I assume both mine and their SQL statements should return the same set of data?

Comment: @user1330974 No, the official answer (which is the one I was saying had poor form, if my last statement was ambiguous) looks wrong; it is effectively returning a `CROSS JOIN` of orders in the amount range paired up with every customer record in the database. The official answer's results are borderline meaningless.

Comment: Their solution is actually wrong. It's a cartesian product. It's also bad form, as Uueerdo has mentioned.

Comment: @Uueerdo and @Strawberry, thank you! I guess if there's no explicit mentioning of the type of `JOIN` like in the official solution, it becomes `CROSS JOIN` (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @user1330974 it is not the lack of specifying the JOIN, it is that there is no actual join condition specified; you would get the same kind of results if you do something like `A INNER JOIN B ON TRUE`.